# Manter imagem com tamanho normal - CSS

Tags: php, jquery, css

bom dia, estou mostrando imagens num slider, so que elas estão sendo esticadas, como q faço no css, para que ela fique no tamanho especificado no css, por exempo: width:200px; e height:200px.
nisso, a imagem pode ser cortada, nao precisa mostrar inteira, mas mantendo ela normal, nao esticando ela:
http://planow.com.br/eco/colecao-masculino-2.php?colecao=receituario_m
veja coleção de fotos...
me ajudem

**COMO RESOLVER:**

```
background-image: url('admin/cache/1404829174269_808646729155217_5122918805829398554_n.jpg');
width: 49%;
height: 49%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Tem como postar o seu código da criação da div com a foto? tanto css como html... Para que possamos lhe ajudar melhor @furlan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode ser feito assim também:

```
<div style="
background-image: url(admin/cache/1404830097269_808646729155217_5122918805829398554_n.jpg);
width: 264px;
height: 177px;
background-size: 262px 177px;"></div>
```

No lugar da tag `<img>`

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a propriedade `background-image` para exibir sua imagem, e os valores `contain` e `cover` para a propriedade `background-size` para definir como a imagem será exibida. Exemplo:

```
<html>
<style>
    .panel {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-image: url('http://www.allamericanbaseballacademy.com/users/SamuelWernick6047/docs/Image//Bucknell%20University%20Baseball.gif');
        border: 2px solid red;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
        margin: 10px;
    }

        .panel.contain {
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .panel.cover {
            background-size: cover;
        }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="panel contain"></div>
    <div class="panel cover"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dVuLr/).

Comment: cara, obrigado, vc salvou o dia !

Comment: Não por isso, fico feliz que tenha funcionado. `Background` geralmente oferece maior funcionalidade para exibição de images do que o elemento `img`.

Comment: mas não é background, é imagem, to tentando aqui

Comment: Caro @Furlan, caso tenha te ajudado a resposta, por favor avalie como resposta correta, para até como agradecimento!